# Trouble integrating Socialize SDK into app

Tags: gradle, socialize-sdk

I´ve been trying to integrate the socialize sdks into my app for some hours now and i just can´t figure out how to do it. i get this anoyying gradle dependancy error:

com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes

I searched on forums and it´s supposed to be a problem with having 2 support libraries like annotations and appcompat 22.2.1 and their annotations interfering but thats not the problem with my project. i think the problem occurs when i add the com.socialize:loop dependancy to the project.

heres a screenshot:

[image]

i´ve tried everything. adding the dependencies as modules, aar and some other stuff. i get this error every time. some help would be greatly apreciated. Thanks =)

it´s a clean project and it´s the only dependencies iv´e imported.
it happens when i add the loopy thing. the problem is, if i don't add the loopy thing it doesn't work because socialize.libary depends on it

Comment: i think socialze sdk doesn't work with appcompat v 22

Comment: Hi Jose Maria, any update on the problem?

Comment: Still can´t do anything to fix it. looking for alternatives. any help would still be greatly appreciated

Comment: I gave up until they fix it. I'm also looking for alternatives. Please share f you can find a good alternative. I will do so.

Comment: did you find an alternative to socialize? they have really poor support.

Comment: @shyamsundar1988 No man, They have terrible support. I ended up implementing everything by myself using postgreSQL, Spring, and AWS

Comment: makes sense.. I dont think i can rely on these guys either.. thanks for your help.